# forcing TLS version 1.2 for a web service consumer running in JBOSS that calls external web service

Tags: java

My application(something.war) that is running on JBOSS makes a call to an external webservice. This web service provider is dropping TLS v1.0 and forcing me to use newer version.

So,  I want to know where should I mention to disable this old version or enable/force to new version.

Will this be a change in standalone.xml or java code (of war file) or some change in jdk/jre used by jboss etc. or somewhere else.

and how can I verify/test which version is being used as its possible that even if I mention somewhere in some configuration, still default/old version is in effect. I won't know because the web service call works fine in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In your jboss config, you can include TLS protocols as generic JRE arguments. This can be added to `standalone.conf`, `host.xml`, or `JAVA_OPTS`, as long as the eventual startup command looks something like this (remove the ones you don't want to enable):

```
java ‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" myApp
```

Note that java clients using the `HttpsURLConnection` class or `URL.openStream()` operations may need this parameter instead, or in addition: `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

---

These can technically be overridden by the java application itself by modifying the `SSLContext` properties, but it's not common

Comment: do you mean the JVM options should be changed? ok. Somewhere I see people suggesting to change in:  <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="sslRealm" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>. and some suggest <security-realm>...<ssl protocol="TLSv1.2"> etc. in the standalone.xml. So, are those same? I feel like these are change for server serving TLSv1.2. But, my case, my app is client (running in jboss) that makes call to external webservice.

Comment: @zoomer those are both going to be the **server-side** TLS settings, for when clients talk to your server. Outbound stuff from your app to another server will use the JRE settings. (there are some exceptions like if your java app launches some shell curl script, that would use the OS TLS settings, but... that would be weird to do). This page shows the client settings that work for most JREs, though it is IBM-flavored: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-change-default-ssltls-protocol-my-java%E2%84%A2-application-will-use

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that those 2 settings (mentioned in my 1st comment) are server-side settings. So, in my case as a web service consumer, I will focus on the suggested JRE setting instead. By the way, for the verification, any idea please :) Do I need to make code changes (logging) etc. to verify its really using the desired version (not the default/old version) or any better way? I heard Wireshark etc. can intercept and maybe we can check TLS version, not sure though. But using this tool also seems a hassle.

Comment: @zoomer You can enable debug logging at the same level like `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and search for `ClientHello` logs to verify, but I wouldn't leave it on all the time. I'm not a java dev, but it looks like you could log your sslContext or sslEngine properties. Take a look at https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html and skip down to "Changing default TLS protocol" for more information. If that was helpful, consider marking this as the answer too, thanks!